# Cannot dynamically change Chosen dropdown selection when form is opened in new window

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen, window.open

I'm opening a new window which contains a form like this

```
OpenedFormWindow = window.open(url, "popup_window", params);

var form_data = selected_option.data();
console.log(form_data);

OpenedFormWindow.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.each(form_data, function (e, v) {
            if (e.startsWith('field_')) {
                e = e.slice(6);

                var inputElement = $(OpenedFormWindow.document).find(':input[name="' + e + '"]');
                console.log(inputElement);

                inputElement.val(v);

                inputElement.trigger('chosen:updated');
                //console.log('test', inputElement.data('chosen'));
            }
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

This form contains a [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) dropdown that I am attempting to update. `form_data` is a key->value pair, where the key is the `name` of the element and the `value` is the value I want to set the dropdown to.

The dropdown in question is defined like this

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Customer</label>

    <?php
        $customers = $pdo->all('SELECT id, name FROM customers');
    ?>
    <select class="form-select" id="customer_dropdown" required name="customer_id">
        <option></option>
        <? foreach($customers as $customer): ?>
            <option <?= $item_data['customer_id'] == $customer['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="<?= $customer['id'] ?>"><?= $customer['name'] ?></option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

And Chosen is initialized in a separate js file.

```
$('select').not('.no_chosen,.ship_to_selector').chosen({ inherit_select_classes: true });
```

Very similar code works in other places in my system, but in this case the dropdown value is not updated. Note, I'm also passing a key->Value pair to update the Product Family input, which is working correctly, so I'm fairly sure this has to do with the Chosen plugin.

[image]

From the console.log in my $.each loop, I can tell the select element IS being picked correctly, and it appears that Chosen is fully initialized at this time, as the chosen-master class has been added to it, and the chosen-container div exists. Just in case, I did add a setTimeout around my $.each but this did not help. I have also verified that the value I am passing does exist in the chosen dropdown.

[image]

How can I update the dropdown in the opened window?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by defining a function that loops over all of the active chosen elements and runs the chosen:updated trigger. This is defined in a global js file.

```
function UpdateLoadedChosenElements() {
    $('select').each(function(e, elem) {
        var elem = $(elem);
        if(elem.data('chosen')) {
            elem.trigger('chosen:updated');
            elem.change();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, I call that function from the opened window after updating the values.

```
OpenedFormWindow = window.open(url, "popup_window", params);

var form_data = selected_option.data();

OpenedFormWindow.onload = function() {

    $(OpenedFormWindow.document).ready(function() {
        $.each(form_data, function (e, v) {
            if (e.startsWith('field_')) {
                e = e.slice(6);

                var inputElement = $(OpenedFormWindow.document).find(':input[name="' + e + '"]');

                inputElement.val(v);
            }
        });

        OpenedFormWindow.UpdateLoadedChosenElements();

    });
}
```